# Which kind of convergence can we get from Laplace transform convergence?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, limits-and-convergence, laplace-transform

This question is a related question see this post [Vague convergence VS Laplace transform convergence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445665/vague-convergence-vs-laplace-transform-convergence). But now we assume that
\begin{equation}
    \int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\mu_n(dx)\to \int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\mu(dx),
\end{equation}

for all $s\in (0, \infty)$, where $\mu_n$ is a finite measure. Please check  this book for [vague convergence](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Foundations_of_Modern_Probability/L6fhXh13OyMC?hl=en&gbpv=0&bsq). Can we get what from the above Laplace transform convergence? From the above post, my understanding is that vague convergence is weaker than weakly convergence (please correct me, if I am wrong). Is it possible to get vague convergence and why or why not?

Comment: This (with $s > 0$ and with $s \geq 0$) are simple consequences of above mentioned  Kallenberg (1997), Lemma 4.4 (approximation). Of course vague convergence is weaker than weak convergence, since for the first fewer test functions are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\thh}{\theta}$In general, you cannot get the vague convergence here. E.g., suppose that $\mu=0$ and $\mu_n(dx)=x^2\,1(n<x<n+1)\,dx$. Then for each real $s>0$
\begin{equation*}
    0\le\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\mu_n(dx)=\int_n^{n+1} e^{-sx}x^2\,dx
    \le e^{-sn}(n+1)^2\to0
\end{equation*}
(as $n\to\infty$), so that
\begin{equation*}
    \int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\mu_n(dx)\to\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\mu(dx). 
\end{equation*}
However, letting $f(x):=\frac1{1+x}$ for real $x\ge0$, we have $f\in C_0([0,\infty))$ and
\begin{equation*}
    \int_0^\infty f(x)\mu_n(dx)=\int_n^{n+1} f(x)x^2\,dx
    \ge \frac1{1+n+1}n^2\to\infty,
\end{equation*}
so that
\begin{equation*}
    \int_0^\infty f(x)\mu_n(dx)\to\infty\ne0=\int_0^\infty f(x)\mu(dx). 
\end{equation*}

---

However, assuming that the measure $\mu$ is finite, you can get the following:
\begin{equation*}
    \int_0^\infty f(x)\mu_n(dx)\to\int_0^\infty f(x)\mu(dx) \tag{$*$}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
for all $f\in C_c([0,\infty))$, that is, for all continuous functions $f$ on $[0,\infty)$ with a compact support.

Indeed, take any such $f$, so that $f=0$ on $[a,\infty)$ for some real $a>0$. Consider first the case when $f\ge0$.

Take any real $h>0$ and let
\begin{equation*}
    \nu_{n,h}(dx):=e^{-hx}\mu_n(dx),\quad \nu_h(dx):=e^{-hx}\mu(dx). 
\end{equation*}
Then for any real $s\ge0$
\begin{equation*}
    \int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\nu_{n,h}(dx)=\int_0^\infty e^{-(s+h)x}\mu_n(dx)
    \to\int_0^\infty e^{-(s+h)x}\mu(dx)=\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\nu_h(dx).  
\end{equation*}
So, by the [previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/445676/36721), $\nu_{n,h}\to\nu_h$ weakly. So,
\begin{equation*}
    \int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-hx}\mu_n(dx)=\int_0^\infty f(x)\nu_{n,h}(dx)
\to\int_0^\infty f(x)\nu_h(dx)=\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-hx}\mu(dx)   
\end{equation*}
for each real $h>0$.
Next,
\begin{equation*}
    \int_0^\infty f(x)\mu_n(dx)\ge\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-hx}\mu_n(dx)
    =\int_0^a f(x)e^{-hx}\mu_n(dx) \\ 
    \ge e^{-ha}\int_0^a f(x)\mu_n(dx)
    =e^{-ha}\int_0^\infty f(x)\mu_n(dx),
\end{equation*}
so that
\begin{equation*}
    \int_0^\infty f(x)\mu_n(dx)=e^{\thh_{n,h,f}ha}\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-hx}\mu_n(dx)
\end{equation*}
for some $\thh_{n,h,f}\in[0,1]$ depending on $n,h,f$. Similarly,
\begin{equation*}
    \int_0^\infty f(x)\mu(dx)=e^{\thh_{h,f}ha}\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-hx}\mu(dx)
\end{equation*}
for some $\thh_{h,f}\in[0,1]$ depending on $h,f$. So, for each real $h>0$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \limsup_n\int_0^\infty f(x)\mu_n(dx)&\le e^{ha}\limsup_n\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-hx}\mu_n(dx) \\ 
&   =e^{ha}\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-hx}\mu(dx) \\ 
&   \le e^{ha}\int_0^\infty f(x)\mu(dx) \\ 
&   \underset{h\downarrow0}\longrightarrow
    \int_0^\infty f(x)\mu(dx)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \liminf_n\int_0^\infty f(x)\mu_n(dx)&\ge\liminf_n\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-hx}\mu_n(dx) \\ 
    &=\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-hx}\mu(dx) \\ 
    &\ge e^{-ha}\int_0^\infty f(x)\mu(dx) \\ 
&   \underset{h\downarrow0}\longrightarrow
    \int_0^\infty f(x)\mu(dx). 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
So, $\limsup_n\int_0^\infty f(x)\mu_n(dx)=\liminf_n\int_0^\infty f(x)\mu_n(dx)=\int_0^\infty f(x)\mu(dx)$ and hence \eqref{1} holds
for any nonnegative $f\in C_c([0,\infty))$.

Finally, writing $f=f_+-f_-$, where $f_\pm:=\max(0,\pm f)$, we get \eqref{1} for all $f\in C_c([0,\infty))$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: $f$ doesn't have compact support.

Comment: @DieterKadelka : No, it does not, and it does not have to, according to the definition of the vague convergence, which involves $C_0$, the space of continuous functions small (but not necessarily $0$) outside some compact sets.

Comment: Kallenberg explicitely demands test functions with compact support.

Comment: @DieterKadelka : Yes, he does, but I think most other people do not. Anyhow, now we have an answer for both versions of the vague convergence.

Comment: By the way, do you have a link where the vague topology is defined by $C_0$ test functions. I only know the definition as in Kallenberg, Topsoe, ...

Comment: @DieterKadelka : I saw that in a couple of places. But what does it matter now?

Comment: @DieterKadelka : [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vague_topology) gives $C_0$ as the principal version, and about the $C_c$ version it says "It is also not uncommon". But again, this is just a choice of terminology.